# Would you draw a comparison between will and should in terms of expressing a command?

Tags: modal-verbs

Can we use 'should' for a second person order?

Comment: Can you give us specific examples of sentences using *will* and *should*?

Comment: "You should give your examples. Will you add your examples?" Both aren't "orders".

Answer (score 1):

The sentence "you should do your work" has less of command and more of necessity. So, 'order' in case of "should" is less pressing than "you will do your work."